# Можно ли описать связь один ко многим таким образом?

Tags: jpa, hibernate, java, orm

Стандартное описание связи один ко многим(для примера) выглядит как-то так

```
public class User {
    .......
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="group_id")
    Group group;
    .......
}

public class Group {
    @OneToMany
    Set<User> users;
}
```

Соответственно чтобы добавить юзера в группу нужно выполнить след. код

```
user.setGroup( group );
```

Мне же нужно, что-то наподобии такого

```
public class User {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="group_id")
    long groupId;
}
```

в коде это будет выглядеть вот так

```
user.setGroupId(  id );
```

Т. е нужна возможность напрямую менять поле с внешним ключом.

Можно ли описать подобную конструкцию и использовать ее, или такой подход не может быть использован? Что-то в сети решений не нашел совсем никаких.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу на свой вопрос:

Небольшое уточнение: В вопросе рассматривалось возможность генерации структуры бд хибернейтом.

Вот здесь можно посмотреть аналогичный мой вопрос на тостере [Можно ли описать связь один ко многим c возможностью изменять поле с внешним ключом?](http://toster.ru/q/120875)

В итоге пришли к выводу, что так сделать, увы, не получится. Решение следующее - либо использовать аннотации один ко многим с нужными объектами, тогда хибернейт сгенерирует нужную структуру, либо описать поле group_id, как обычное поле, и уже отдельно с помошь дополнительного sql скрипта проапдейтить базу, прописав внешние ключи, тогда хибернейт ничего не будет знать про внешний ключ, и позволит использовать описанную мной структуру.